# Problem inserting a 32-digit number into an array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program to store a 32-bit number into an Array.
 For Example, the number: 11000001110010000000000000000000 
 In the array, arr[0] would be 1 as that is the first digit.

However I am unable to get the desired output. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int binarynumber;
    int arr[32];
    printf("Enter A binary Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &binarynumber);
    for (int i = 32; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        arr[i] = binarynumber % 10;
        binarynumber /= 10;
    }
    printf("The first digit is %d", arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: c and c++ are totally different languages please don't tag them both,

Comment: What will be the input? `3251109888` or `11000001110010000000000000000000`? If latter, you can't `scanf()` that into an int. If it is the first, then in the loop you need %2 and /2, instead of 10. Also, start `i` from 0 and loop upto 31

Comment: It would be the latter. Which method could I use to input it instead?

Comment: Then you need to get the input as string

Comment: Would that be using str binarynumber and Scanf(%s,&binarynumber) ?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd read it as a string and iterate through each character and added (and converted) them to the int array. As mentioned, typing the 32 digit long number is too big to store inside an int.

Comment: How would a code for this option look like?

Answer (score 0):

I guess bitwise operations should do the job

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int binarynumber;
    int arr[32];
    printf("Enter A binary Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &binarynumber);
    int array_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
    for (int i = 0, j = array_size - 1; i < array_size; i++, j--) 
    {
        int binarynumber_copy = binarynumber;
        // shifting number `j` bits right and cutting off one bit by bitwise AND
        arr[i] = (binarynumber_copy >> j) & 1;
    }
    printf("The first digit is %d", arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: But OP wants input as `11000001110010000000000000000000` not any decimal number. So, this will not satisfy OP's need. Also  the terminating condition for the loop is wrong. It should be `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. Otherwise it will lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you want user to input `11000001110010000000000000000000`, then you can't get that whole number in an integer. So, if the user enters `3251109888` (decimal of `11000001110010000000000000000000`), then better to get the number as **unsigned int**. Also you need to convert it to binary in the loop using %2 and /2. The loop will run from 0 to 31, so that arr[0] contains the LSB. The code will look like this -

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned int number;
    int arr[32];
    printf("Enter A binary Number:\n");
    scanf("%u", &number);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = number % 2;
        number /= 2;
    }

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want the user to input as `11000001110010000000000000000000`, you need to get that input as string and then convert it into the digit using loop. To do that you can use -

```
int main ()
{
    int arr[32];
    char number[33] = {};
    scanf("%32s", number); // This will scan max 32 characters

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = number[i] - '0';
    }

    printf("arr[0]: %d\n", arr[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You may want to validate whether the input contains only digit or not using `isdigit()` inside the loop

Comment: Ohh i see, thank you this was what I was looking for!

Comment: can I check where does the string variable come from?

Comment: @Exx, Sorry, updated the answer